# Rails and Paperclip Endless POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am having an issue with paperclip. I have everything set up right, but when I click submit the server freezes and I end up in an endless post request to localhost.

Here's my model:

`class Audio < ApplicationRecord
  has_attached_file :audio
end`

My new form:

```
<%= form_for @audio do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :audio %>
    <%= f.file_field :audio, class: 'form-control'%>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit 'Upload', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>

<% end %>
```

And finally my controller:

```
def new
    @audio = Audio.new
  end

  def create
    @audio = Audio.new(audio_params)
    if @audio.save
      flash[:success] = "The audio was added!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Here's my schema for good measure:

```
create_table "audios", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "audio_file_name"
    t.string "audio_content_type"
    t.integer "audio_file_size"
    t.datetime "audio_updated_at"
  end
```

Comment: Note, this doesn't even register as a post request in console. my logs end at GET /new and the clicking the submit button freezes the server and I have to force quit ruby to restart it

Comment: Your form is not multipart. And in your controller you have to assign the audio file upload to your record such as `@audio.audio = params[:audio][:audio]`